# How to find users who logged in every single day to the app?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm trying to get the details of the power users of my app. So trying to fetch the list of users who have used the app `every single day` or `N out of M days`. `(N < M)`

I'm new to BigQuery and found this query on [Google Sample queries](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9037342?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512#frequentactives) that finds `users who have logged at least one event with event param engagement_time_msec > 0 on N of the last M days where M > N.`

I have modified the query to make sure it doesn't count multiple logins on a single day. So the below query gives me number of users who logged in the app every single day (not counting mutiple logins the same day. I used `distinct` in the last `HAVING` clause)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS frequent_active_users_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      user_id,
      COUNT(DISTINCT event_date)
    FROM
      -- PLEASE REPLACE WITH YOUR TABLE NAME.
      `YOUR_TABLE.events_*` AS T
    CROSS JOIN
      T.event_params
    WHERE
      event_params.key = 'engagement_time_msec' AND event_params.value.int_value > 0
      -- User engagement in the last M = 10 days.
      AND event_timestamp >
          UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
      -- PLEASE REPLACE YOUR DESIRED DATE RANGE.  For optimal performance
      -- the _TABLE_SUFFIX range should match the INTERVAL value above.
      AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20230101' AND '20230110'
    GROUP BY 1
    -- Having engaged in at least N = 10 days.
    HAVING COUNT(distinct event_date) >= 10
  );
```

Now this query has date range mentioned as `_TABLE_SUFFIX`. But I want to visualize this in Data Studio where I can select mutiple dates myself.

1. How to make this query date-range agnostic? It means taking all dates into consideration and then filtering on Data Studio.
2. How to make the N and M also variables that I can play around in Data Studio?

Can someone please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You might use *custom query with parameters* in Looker Studio.

#### Parameterized Custom Query in Looker Studio

###### ■ 1st Step - write down *Custom SQL with parameters*

[image]

###### ■ 2nd Step - link paraters with controls

[image]

#### Sample `Custom SQL` with parameters

I've simplified your query to show you working example.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS frequent_active_users_count FROM (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id,
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce.events_*`
   WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE
   GROUP BY 1
   -- Having engaged in at least N = 2 days.
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT event_date) >= @n
);
```

**Visualization with Scorecard**

[image]