# Create a dynamic parameter on looker studio (old data studio)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying to create a dynamic table where the values are based on the input data (url in this case). I want to add a parameter in a custom query that uses SQL where I want to filter results based on the input done at the report level.

```
SELECT fromURL.url,toURL.url,anchorText FROM `source1`
WHERE fromURL.url = @url
```

Now I need to define the parameter @url in a way that results are based on the user input in the report. Can someone help me?

Comment: hope this helps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75182434/how-to-find-users-who-logged-in-every-single-day-to-the-app/75191190#75191190

Comment: thanks @Jaytiger! that's very useful but not for this specific case as the type is text and not number. thanks anyway